# Draw minimal with drawRect and setNeedsDisplayInRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

He, I just realized that [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:(dRect)] draws everything (and not only the necessary) and then updates the screen in "dRect". So I started to edit the drawRect-method like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    if (gUs==1){
        imagePos = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
        [_bz_BG dissolveToPoint:imagePos fraction:1.0];
        [self drawBPM];
        [self writeSeq1steps];
        [self writeSeq2steps];
        [self drawSeq1Patterns];
        [self drawSeq2Patterns];
        [self drawSeq1];
        [self drawSeq2];
        [self drawSampleNameSeq1];
        [self drawSampleNameSeq2];
        [self drawBattCharge];
        [self drawCPUload];}
    if (gUs==2){
        [self drawCPUload];}
    if (gUs==3){
        [self drawBattCharge];}
    if (gUs==4){
        [self drawBPM];}
}
```

and then let the methods that need display alter "gUs". That works fine and since I have a lot of controls reduces the cpu work extremely.

But then I saw that under heavy load or often display updates sometimes another method alters "gUs" before the needDisplay from the previous call is processed, leading to wrong drawings.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What is `gUs`?  Why aren't you testing if the dirty rect affects those elements before drawing them?

Comment: gUs is set by the method before its setNeedsDisplay. And how to test that?

Comment: You need to know the rect occupied by each element and test for intersection with the dirty rect.  This is how you avoid unnecessary drawing.

Comment: Ok, reading "Constraining Drawing to Improve Performance" now... thanks for pointing.